# Win32: enabling visual styles in MinGW without manifest

Tags: winapi, mingw

I have a Win32 project which I compile with MinGW. I would like to enable visual styles in this program without requiring an external manifest.

With MSVC, this apparently can be done with the following pragma:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

However, GCC (MinGW) does not support such a pragma. Is there a way for me to emulate the behavior of this pragma with MinGW?

Comment: The MSVC pragma just results in a manifest resource being added by the linker. If you don't use a manifest then you'd need to use runtime linking and an activation context to load the comctl32 dll. I don't even know if that's possible. It's a lot of work even if it is. Use a manifest already.

Comment: Simply write a `.rc` file that refers to a `.manifest` file, then compile the `.rc` file into a `.res` file using any resource compiler you want, then instruct MinGW's linker to link that `.res` file into your final executable alongside your source code's compiled object files. That is basically what the `#pragma` is doing behind the scenes, just without using actual `.rc` or `.manifest` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems as if writing a resource/manifest is the only way forward here, so I have to proceed that way.